# Отказано в доступе по пути, как решить? (Программа запущена от имени администратора, манифест тоже настроен)

Tags: c#, загрузка, доступ, google-drive

Пишу небольшую программу, которая по нажатию кнопки скачивает файл с GoogleDrive. Сам API я для этого поставил, пишу следующий код и получаю ошибку по причине "Отказано в доступе по пути", хотя запускаю Visual Studio от имени администратора, манифест настроил, точнее поменял там одну строку, как написано в интернете. Уже дал полный доступ своему пользователю ко всему диску C и в свойствах диска убрал атрибут только для чтения, но ничего не помогает, что еще надо?

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DriveService service = new DriveService();
            var stream = service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dt- 
            SXQmwcHlZMEuV7rfz-0SHwTLKIiCR/view?usp=sharing");
            var result = stream.Result;
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" +                Environment.UserName.ToString() + @"\AppData\Roaming"))
            {
                result.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вы не забыли добавить в конце пути имя файла? Если нет, то что Вы ожидаете от этого `File.Create`?

Comment: Еще, вставьте в вопрос полную информацию об ошибке (тип, сообщение, трассировку стека). И да, если со скачиванием с Google Drive проблем нет, то эту часть можно убрать наверное.

Comment: забыл уточнить, что я скачиваю не файл, а целую папку с кучей фалов

Comment: Ну и к `AppData` путь лучше брать через `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Если да, отметьте наиболее полезный ответ галочкой.

Answer (score 4):

Проиллюстрирую всё, о чем пишут в соседнем ответе и комментах, плюс исправил ошибку асинхронности

```cs
private async void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DriveService service = new DriveService();
    using var stream = await service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dt-SXQmwcHlZMEuV7rfz-0SHwTLKIiCR/view?usp=sharing");
    string myFolder = @"Downloads\";
    string filename = "file.txt";
    using var fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, myFolder, filename));
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`File.Create` создает файл по заданному пути. Вы передаете в метод путь к папке. Метод пытается создать файл с именем «Roaming» в папке «AppData». Возникает ошибка, т.к. нельзя создавать файл с таким же именем как уже существующая папка в том же расположении.

Почему то при этом выбрасывается `UnauthorizedAccessException` хотя в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-5.0) такой случай не описывается.

Чтобы исправить нужно добавить имя файла:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"...\Roaming\icon.png"))
```

> забыл уточнить, что я скачиваю не файл, а целую папку с кучей фалов

В коде это не написано. Если так, то нужно разбирать файлы и для каждого создавать файл с соответствующим названием.